# UITableView - how to make search bar scroll with table

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I make the search bar to scroll together with the table view? When I scroll my table view I want my search bar to go with it and disappear. I want to have done something similar to contacts app on the iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place your searchbar in the [tableView's header row](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW32).  This will make it part of the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an empty table section, above or ahead of all other sections in your table view. Set this section's header to be your search bar view.